# Where does Barry Allen live?

Tags: character, arrowverse, the-flash

Has it been established where Barry Allen lives? Most of the time we see him off duty, he's either in his empty lab at CCPD or at Star Labs.

Does he have an apartment, or did he move back to the West home after college? (We see him at the West home at Christmas, but he could be just visiting.)

Comment: Will you pay him a visit? :)

Comment: Ha! I just thought it was odd that we haven't seen his home life at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the end of Season 1's "Revenge of the Rogues" Barry moves back into the West house, both to keep Joe company after Iris moves out and because he says it's getting harder to conceal his comings and goings as the Flash from the neighbors at his apartment.